# How to use pagereference outside a method

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I am used to using PageReference in a method like so:

```
public PageReference transPage()
{
    PageReference newPage = page.PAGE_NAME;
    newPage.getParameters().put('ContactId', selContact.Id);
    newPage.getParameters().put('ContactName', selContact.Name);
    newPage.getParameters().put('AccountId', selContact.Account.Id);
    newPage.getParameters().put('AccountName', selContact.Account.Name); 
    return newPage;
}
```

I am looking to turn the method into a public void and include an if statement where if true will send to a new page but if false will send an error message.

The help is greatly appreciated in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just return a null PageReference, this will simply refresh the page.

```
public PageReference transPage()
{
    PageReference newPage = page.PAGE_NAME;
    newPage.getParameters().put('ContactId', selContact.Id);
    newPage.getParameters().put('ContactName', selContact.Name);
    newPage.getParameters().put('AccountId', selContact.Account.Id);
    newPage.getParameters().put('AccountName', selContact.Account.Name); 

    if (errorCondition == true) {

        // Add error message to page here
        return null;

    } else {

        return newPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by returning null instead.

```
public PageReference transPage()
{
  if (something)
    return null;

  PageReference newPage = page.PAGE_NAME;
  newPage.getParameters().put('ContactId', selContact.Id);
  newPage.getParameters().put('ContactName', selContact.Name);
  newPage.getParameters().put('AccountId', selContact.Account.Id);
  newPage.getParameters().put('AccountName', selContact.Account.Name); 
  return newPage;
}
```